# horrible list of dicts to iterate over

Tags: python

I have this dictionary which is pulled from radb.net (use for network irr info)
(some data sanitized)

```
{'objects': {'object': [{'type': 'route',
    'attributes': {'attribute': [{'value': '10.10.10.0/22', 'name': 'route'},
      {'name': 'descr', 'value': 'MyCorp Services, Inc.'},
      {'name': 'origin',
       'link': {'href': 'http://radb.net/api/radb/aut-num/AS11111',
        'type': 'locator'},
       'value': 'AS11111',
       'referenced-type': 'aut-num'},
      {'link': {'href': 'http://radb.net/api/radb/mntner/MAINT-RADB-AS11111',
        'type': 'locator'},
       'name': 'mnt-by',
       'value': 'MAINT-RADB-AS11111',
       'referenced-type': 'mntner'},
      {'name': 'changed', 'value': 'me@MyCorp.com 20201006'},
      {'value': 'RADB', 'name': 'source'}]},
    'primary-key': {'attribute': [{'value': '10.10.10.0/22', 'name': 'route'},
      {'name': 'origin', 'value': 'AS11111'}]},
    'source': {'id': 'radb'},
    'link': {'type': 'locator',
     'href': 'http://radb.net/api/radb/route/10.10.10.0/22AS11111'}}]},
 'service': {'name': 'search'},
 'terms-and-conditions': {'type': 'locator',
  'href': 'http://www.radb.net/register/'}}
```

All i really want to be able to do is print out the value `'10.10.10.0/22'`

I'm like 3x `for` lines into a loop but figure there must be a better way

code so far:

```
for k,v in horrible_dict.items():
       if 'object' in v:
          for x,y in v.items():
                for k,v in [(k, v) for x in y for (k, v) in x.items()]:
                    print(v)
                    for....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract only that value you could do:

```
dic = #your dictionary
val = dic["objects"]["object"][0]["attributes"]["attribute"][0]["value"]

>>> val
'10.10.10.0/22'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be with nested list comprehension if you have several values.

```
from itertools import chain

result = [
      [
    [g[0]['value'] for f,g in e['attributes'].items()] 
    for e in v['object']
  ] 
    for k,v in horrible_dict.items() if 'object' in v
]

list(chain.from_iterable(result))[0]
>>>
['11.11.11.0/22']
```